# Chef server api_fqdn is ignored

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to set up private chef server in AWS environment. In file `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` I have:

`api_fqdn = 'chef.shared.internal'`

nevertheless when I run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` this setting is completely ignored. I can remove it from file, place again, change value - all these has no effect - the server is always configured to hostname, which is on AWS `ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal`!

I'm running chef-server-core-12.18.14-1 on ubuntu-18.04.

Does anybody knows the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After looging in the chef server code I found kind of workaround. It looks to me like it is broken in cookboobks that used by chef-server-ctl. In order to make everything be configured to desired fqnd I need to put the following configuration to `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb`

```
    api_fqdn = 'chef.shared.internal'
    lb['api_fqdn'] = api_fqdn
    lb['web_ui_fqdn'] = api_fqdn
    nginx['server_name'] = api_fqdn
    nginx['url'] = "https://#{api_fqdn}"
```

In the defaiul cookbook all these values set to `node['fqdn']` by default instead of `node['private_chef']['api_fqdn']`